# Is a resumé/CV required for a freelancer?

Tags: business, freelance, resume

Since a freelancer usually (or from what I understand) takes on all aspects of their work, they don't really get hired for permanent positions and thus work off individual projects. A client hires the designer based off a portfolio and if the price/style/etc is a match, the project moves forward.

At least this is what my understanding is. If a freelancer isn't interested in being hired for permanent work, do they need a resumé to prove their skills when a portfolio is (in my opinion) has a much greater impact on what a designer can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely your portfolio will be your star piece, but some sort of **online profile** can help too.

When you are working with a freelancing site, you can upload your pieces and your work experience in your user page. That makes it easier to keep things centralized, as clients can see your rating as well as your work.

But if you are contacted by a client outside those networks, I've found it useful to refer possible clients to my LinkedIn address as well as my personal/portfolio site. They can potentially leave feedback/recommendations in there too, that are then easily accessible by anyone. If it's the case, a resume is also useful to show you have worked in other environments such as offices or agencies.

Answer (score 0):

Portfolio, web site, client testimonials, referral are all *far, far, far*  more important.

My resumé/CV has absolutely no use as a freelancer, at least not in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Resume is not required but at some stage your client will ask for that and it can create a good impression...

you can also create your online blog or portfolio that can describe your profile in far batter way and can be more effective than resume.

Answer (score 0):

A resume is a record of your past work experience and education. It's basically all the milestones you've achieved, in chronological order (generally).

We are graphic designers. One of our jobs is to represent data we have in an easily understandable manner that is pleasing to look at. Why not take this as a design challenge and make a resume in the form of an infographic or a timeline? Just suggestions.

Doing this on your personal website would be really great and effective. Your prospective clients will know your qualifications, and will also see you are good at what you do. This is also a great way to showcase any awards or recognition you've got.

That being said, your portfolio is still the most important aspect of your proposal. But resumes don't have to be boring. They should just solve their purpose - to let the viewer know what the person's past record is. And as designers one of our jobs is to... oh wait I've already said that.

Peace out.
Payod.